# Obj-C, iPhone, how can send the database file used in my app home for support?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to track down some bugs experienced by a user.

I'm just thinking the easiest thing, if she was willing, might be to have a feature would would send the database file to me.

How would I get at the file and send it ?

I don't think attaching it to an email would be the best idea, but I can't think of anything simple ?

Ideas ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a huge privacy risk. Might even get the app rejected by Apple.

Comment: I will rather adopt a logging system like GTMLogger and send a log file containing catched errors

Comment: @mjisrawi, thats a good point.

Comment: @daveoncode, it's going to a bit more complicated that logging, although I could log all insert and update queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of sending the DB via **email** probably is the simplest mechanism.  Not sure Apple would have an issue with this as long as the user is aware they are sending their data to the App Support team.

Aside from the email idea, you could extract the data of interest into an XML format that could be easily pasted into the body of an email, or sent via HTTP POST back to your server.  Likewise, you could HTTP POST the entire DB file back to the server, or to a Dropbox account, using the Dropbox API.

You would use the NSFileManager class to get at the DB file contents in order to send back to the server.